# How to get logged user name in MS Access 2007?

Tags: database, ms-access, vba

I want to get logged username in MS Access 2007, I wrote that code

```
txt = ENVIRON("username")
```

But it gives me the username of windows, I already create a users table tblUser

Please help

Comment: What's the difference between the user name of windows and the logged user name?

Comment: the logged user name exists in the table that i created in my database  tblUser ..

Comment: And how should the "logged user name" be determined?

Comment: thats my question too , i don't know how

Comment: So, what is that username then? If it is not the login username of windows, there must be some other rule...

Comment: Read the answer to understand  ..

Comment: Which answer? **You** asked this question and you should know the source of the username. Should it be computed by the Windows login name? Should it be something from a database? Should the user enter it manually? Is there any login system to take the name from?

Comment: you don't read my question very good,  i already create a table tblUser contain username

Comment: You don't read my questions very good: where is the connection between the user running access and that table you are mentioning?

Comment: okey i will excplain to you,  i want to get user name i write the code environ("username") it gives me user windows , i don't want user windows ..
i want user name in table tblUser inside Access because login page contain the login name and password is from tblUser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution :

in code button login i add a variable

```
Private Sub login_Click()
Dim TempID As TempVars 
... 
TempVars!TempID = Me.Username.Value
..
..
End Sub
```

Then in the other form i put a textbox 
Property Sheet of textbox -> Name 'txtwelcome', Control Source -> Expression Builder : [TempVars]![TempID]

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
Debug.Print DLookup("[Logged Name]", "tblUsers", "[username]='" & Environ("Username") & "'")
```

My table tblUsers got 2 fields: Field Username is the Environ Username, and field Logged Name is the name of the user inside Access. Adapt the code to your needs.

Comment: this is my table tblUser(id,username, loginname,pwd) i write the code 

Debug.Print DLookup("[loginname]", "tblUser", "[username]='" & Environ("username") & "'")

is that correct !
but i want to get the name on a textbox so i should write txt = DLook.... 
i try that but doesn't work

Comment: But your tblsUser have no field Environ Username. You have to relationate each record to an Environ Username. If not, the code above won't work.

Comment: how to relationate each record to an Environ Username ?

Comment: Just add a new Field into your table and fill the data. But looking the questions you are doing, maybe you should start, first of all, learning Access, tables, fields, data type, then learn queries, then learn forms, then learn reports and after you learn all that, then try to learn VBA Access and come back here.

Answer (score 0):

As you're using Access 2007 you could use TempVars.  When your user logs in to your access application, you can capture the username they login with as a temp variable and then access that at anytime during their logged in session.

Assuming they have to click an OK button or similar after they have filled in their username and password, put this into the onClick event of that button -

```
TempVars.Add "UserName", Me.YourUserNameField
```

You can then check what that username is from anywhere in your code using

```
=[TempVars]![EmpName]
```

Comment: i put the first code on the button 
and the next into my textbox to show the logged user name ,but doesn't work

Comment: @JamilaAmallou do you get any errors?  Can you screenshot the design view of your login page so I can see what you have so far?

Comment: Login : txtusername         
Password : txtpassword 
 and button login 
this is my page login contains i want to get username and show it on other form

Comment: Ok, and what is the bound field name of your  txtusername control, and what code runs when the user clicks the login button?